# Where does autoconf's AC_CHECK_HEADERS verify the header files?

Tags: header, include, autoconf

I am having trouble with compiling one of the open source libraries (libopekele OpenID lib).

The problem is I don't have sudo access on the system where I need to compile this.

Ran the configure. It complained of missing htmltidy lib.
Installed the htmltidy at a *non-standard* path /home/geekgod (as I dont have access to the `/usr` and `/usr/local`).

Now the problem is how do I make the configure script of libopekele to pick the the headers from `/home/geekgod/include`.

Poking into the `configure.ac` script of libopkele, it is using `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` to search for `tidy.h` or `tidy/tidy.h`.
I am pretty sure it is looking for these at standard location (/usr/include).
How do I add `/home/geekgod` to the standard include dir?

Comment: To answer your question mechanically: `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` compiles a small test program, using the compiler for whichever language is selected by `AC_LANG_PUSH` and `AC_LANG_POP` (C is the default). This sees `CPPFLAGS`, which is how you pass additional search paths to the compiler.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try this:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/home/geekgod/include --prefix=... --etc
```

Comment: +1: You'll probably also want to add LDFLAGS=-L/home/geekgod/lib

Comment: Thanks guys, I required both LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS to be set.